# Android - Kapt Build Fails

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, kapt

I decided to start a project in android and currently I am having this error. I was having another one that was produced by the databinding dependency which had to match the gradle version. After fixing that, I am still receiving this other error when I'm trying to build my project.

This is **my gradle scan report.**
[Gradle Scan](https://scans.gradle.com/s/xsu6youw2f622/)

I have already invalidated cache/restart, clean and rebuild but the problem persists.

The task that is failing is:  `Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED`

This is the output in the console when I run the command

./gradlew build --stacktrace

```
[kapt] An exception occurred: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizeInputFilePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.run(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.LocalTaskInfoExecutor.execute(LocalTaskInfoExecutor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:277)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareWorkItemExecutor.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:262)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:135)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:200)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeWithWork(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:191)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:130)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:143)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:24)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:49)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$ExecuteTasks.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.runTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:219)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.executeTasks(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:77)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.call(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:154)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(StopShieldingWorkerLeaseService.java:38)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:96)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$1.transform(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:79)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.execute(ParallelismConfigurationBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:62)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:295)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:14)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:120)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:152)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:147)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunner.runJvmCompilerAsync(GradleKotlinCompilerRunner.kt:87)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithKotlincTask.compile(KaptWithKotlincTask.kt:72)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:801)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:768)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:300)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:292)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:99)
    ... 111 more


* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 33s
```

Here is the informations about my dependencies

dependencies.gradle

```
ext {
    versions = [
            support         : "28.0.0",
            firebase        : '16.0.6',
            room            : "2.1.0-alpha04",
            constraintLayout: "2.0.0-alpha3",
            moshi           : "1.8.0",
            okHttp          : "3.12.0",
            retrofit        : '2.5.0',
            dagger          : '2.20',
            butterKnife     : '10.0.0',
            rxKotlin        : '2.3.0',
            rxAndroid       : '2.1.0',
            rxPermissions   : '0.9.4@aar',
            sqlbrite        : '1.1.2',
            traceur         : '1.0.1',
            stetho          : '1.5.0',
            timber          : '4.7.1',
            glide           : '4.8.0',
            sherlock        : '1.0.4@aar',
        espresso        : '3.0.2',
        testRunner      : '1.0.2',
        hamcrest        : '2.1',
        restMock        : '0.3.2',
        mockito         : '2.23.4',
        junit           : '4.12',
        robolectric     : '4.1',
        assertj         : '1.2.0',
        powerMock       : '1.6.6',
        leakcanary      : '1.6.2',
        stethOkhttp     : '1.5.0',
        multiDex        : '2.0.1',
        mockitoKotlin   : '1.6.0'
]

mockito = [mockito: "org.mockito:mockito-core:$versions.mockito"]
junit = [junit: "junit:junit:$versions.junit"]
restMock = [restMock: "com.github.andrzejchm.RESTMock:android:$versions.restMock"]

supportDeps = [
        cardView         : "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$versions.support",
        appcompatV7      : "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$versions.support",
        design           : "com.android.support:design:$versions.support",
        recyclerView     : "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$versions.support",
        supportAnnotation: "com.android.support:support-annotations:$versions.support",
        gridLayout       : "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:$versions.support",
        constraintlayout : "com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:$versions.constraintLayout",
        multiDex         : "com.android.support:multidex:$versions.multiDex"
]

room = [
         room: "androidx.room:room-runtime:$versions.room",
         rxjsupp:  "androidx.room:room-rxjava2:$versions.room",
         coroutines: "androidx.room:room-coroutines:$versions.room"
]

rxJava = [
        rxKotlin : "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxkotlin:$versions.rxKotlin",
        rxAndroid: "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$versions.rxAndroid",
        traceur         : "com.tspoon.traceur:traceur:$versions.traceur",
        rxRermissions   : "com.tbruyelle.rxpermissions:rxpermissions:$versions.rxPermissions"
]

retrofit = [
        retrofit     : "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$versions.retrofit",
        rxAdapter    : "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$versions.retrofit",
        moshiConverter: "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:$versions.retrofit",
        sqlbrite     : "com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:$versions.sqlbrite"
]

moshi = [
        moshi: "com.squareup.moshi:moshi-kotlin:$versions.moshi"
]

okHttp = [
        logger: "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.12.1",
        okhttp  : "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$versions.okHttp",
        stetho  : "com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp3:$versions.stetho"
]

googlePlay = [
        maps             : "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0",
        crash            : "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:16.2.1",
        firebaseCore     : "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$versions.firebase",
        firebaseMessaging: "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4"
]


onlyDebug = [
        chuck   : "com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library:1.1.0"
]

onlyRelease = [
        chuckNoOp       : 'com.readystatesoftware.chuck:library-no-op:1.1.0',
        sherlockNoOp    : 'com.github.ajitsing:sherlock-no-op:1.0.4@aar'
]

unitTest = [
        harcrestCore        : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:$versions.hamcrest",
        harmcrestLib        : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:$versions.hamcrest",
        hamcrestIntegration : "org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.4-atlassian-1",
        robolectric         : "org.robolectric:robolectric:$versions.robolectric",
        supportAnnotation   : "com.android.support:support-annotations:$versions.support",
        restMock            : "com.github.andrzejchm.RESTMock:android:$versions.restMock",
        assertj             : "com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:$versions.assertj",
        kotlinTest          : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version",
        kotlinJunit         : "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version",
        mockitoKotlin       : "com.nhaarman:mockito-kotlin:$versions.mockitoKotlin",
        room                : "androidx.room:room-testing:$versions.room"

] + junit + mockito + restMock

androidTests = [
        mockitoAndroid      : "org.mockito:mockito-android:$versions.mockito",
        espressoCore        : "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:$versions.espresso",
        espressoContrib     : "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:$versions.espresso",
        espressoIntents     : "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:$versions.espresso",
        espressoAcc         : "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-accessibility:$versions.espresso",
        espressoIdle        : "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:$versions.espresso",
        espressoConcurrent  : "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-concurrent:$versions.espresso",
        espressoNetIdle     : "com.android.support.test.espresso.idling:idling-net:$versions.espresso",
        testRunner          : "com.android.support.test:runner:$versions.testRunner",
        testRules           : "com.android.support.test:rules:$versions.testRunner"
] + mockito + restMock

leakCannary = "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.6.2"
timber = "com.jakewharton.timber:timber:$versions.timber"
sherlock = "com.github.ajitsing:sherlock:$versions.sherlock"

dagger = "com.google.dagger:dagger:$versions.dagger"
daggerCompiler = "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$versions.dagger"

butterKnife = "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$versions.butterKnife"
butterKnifeCompiler = "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$versions.butterKnife"

glide = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$versions.glide"
glideCompiler = "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$versions.glide"
glideOkhttp = "com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:$versions.glide"
databindingCompiler = "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.3.0"

roomKapt =  "androidx.room:room-compiler:$versions.room"

googlePlayLibs = googlePlay.values()
supportLibs = supportDeps.values()
networkLibs = retrofit.values() + okHttp.values() + moshi.values()
rxJavaLibs = rxJava.values()
otherLibs = [butterKnife, timber, dagger, glide] + room.values()

debugLibs = onlyDebug.values() + leakCannary
releaseLibs = onlyRelease.values() + leakCannary
annotationProcessorLibs = [butterKnifeCompiler, daggerCompiler, glideCompiler, roomKapt]

unitTestLibs = unitTest.values() + leakCannary
androidTestsLibs = androidTests.values() + supportLibs


 }
```

My app/build.gradle file:
[app/build.gradle](https://pastebin.com/nFAypZHm)

My gradle.properties file:
[gradle.properties](https://pastebin.com/wuQDqsZ6)

Comment: What is the solution?  I have a similar error.

Answer (score 1):

### Room and Kapt plugin issue fix

On the right hand side of your IDE, click on the Gradle bar -> app -> tasks -> build -> assemble.
to assemble the debug.

Answer (score 1):

Try

"Build" -> "Clean Project" first, then "Rebuild Project"

Finally goto

"File" -> "Invalidate Cache / Restart"

If you're using ROOM, make sure your DAO is correct